# Why do I have to hit enter multiple times to reload page when the focus is in the URL bar?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

Since a couple of weeks (maybe a month or so) I have a weird behavior in Google Chrome:

1. I click in the URL bar.
2. I press "enter". Nothing happens.
3. I press "enter" again. The page gets reloaded and the marked

Is this a bug? Is this intended behavior? Is there a known way to change it?

### Confirmed Chrome versions

> Ubuntu 18.04; Google Chrome Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Apparently this is expected behaviour: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/8446864?hl=en

Answer (score 5):

It seems timing related: if you keep hitting ‘enter’ quickly after clicking the bar, you can rack up to 7 presses before something happens, depending on your key pressing skills. Waiting about 3 seconds between clicking and pressing ‘enter’, or holding the key down for a few seconds, avoids the need for multiple presses. Of course having to remember to do this is just as unintuitive as pressing multiple times.

I have searched through chrome://flags but I found nothing that seems related.
I use Chrome on Linux, Mac OS X and Windows, and they all exhibit this behavior. Given that a fixed delay seems to be implemented, it might be deliberate although I cannot come up with a plausible motivation for it.

I suggest using the ‘Help’ → ‘Report an issue…’ item in the Chrome menu to report this as I just did. If multiple users do this, they might pay attention to it.

Edit: this is now fixed at last, the fix is in Chrome version 77.0.3865.35 or newer.

Comment: Thank goodness this is now fixed.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be an official bug

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/8446864?hl=en

Copying here the workaround posted by Benjamin Hardin:

> Solution: disable "Autocomplete searches and URLs." Settings => Expand "Advanced" => Expand 
>   "Sync and Google services" => Disable "Autocomplete searches and URLs".

Comment: This was already posted 2 days ago as a comment to the question.